# SonarQube Lombok Getter recognition

Tags: sonarqube, lombok, sonarqube-4.5

I am using SonarQube 4.5.4 with Java plugin 3.1. As I know this sonar-java version supports [Lombok partially (Getter and Setter annotations) starting from 2.8](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-73).
But in my case it still reports field with `lombok.Getter` as:

```
squid:S1068  Unused private fields should be removed:
@Getter
private String userName;
```

Do you have any ideas why this could happen and where can I fix it?

**update**

For bytecode I tried both `sonar.java.binaries` and `sonar.binaries`
I use sbt and run analysis with sonar-runner for below *sonar-project.properties*

```
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.java.binaries=\
    target/scala-2.11/classes,\
    target/scala-2.11/test-classes

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.projectName=projectName  
sonar.host.url=http://hostname:9000  
sonar.login=login  
sonar.password=password  
sonar.projectKey=projectKey:webJava  
sonar.modules=app  
app.sonar.projectBaseDir=web  
app.sonar.sources=app  
app.sonar.tests=test

sonar.analysis.mode=preview  
sonar.issuesReport.lightModeOnly=false
```

Comment: How do you provide java bytecode to the analysis ? are you using maven ? if not can you post your sonar-project.properties ?

Comment: details were added to question body

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide the 3rd party libraries you use (ie your classpath) via `sonar.java.libraries` property for the analyzer to be able to detect that you are using Lombok and make the correct exclusions.

Comment: @benzonico I am using gradle to build the project, so what should I put for the sonar.java.librares property?

Comment: you would have to provide your classpath, ie path to the libraries you are using.

Comment: sonar.java.libraries=/jenkins/jenkins-user-home/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.20/lombok-1.16.20.jar