# Why does SonarQube consider a private filed as unused?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have created a class as follows:

```
package classes;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {
    
    private String title;
    private String number;
    
    public Book(String title, String number) {
        this.title = title;
        this.number = number;
    }
   
}
```

When I analyse this code with SonarQube I get the following code smell:

[image]

Why does SonarQube consider this field as unused?

Comment: Because you're never actually using it, just assigning it a value. You should have a getter or something inside the class that uses its value.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, he's using Lombok which generates getters on the fly

Comment: @amseager apparently SonarQube doesn't know.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073532/sonarqube-lombok-getter-recognition

Comment: that means you dont even have a getter for that number.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca in fact you are right it's a duplicate. I tried what they recommended and it worked. So thanks!